# How to create an update patch for windows application

Tags: c#, patch

How do I create an update patch that updates the application without having to reinstall the application in newer version?

Also, how could I combine other software such as SQL express and printer driver with the application setup file?

I have used Visual Studio 2010 to develop my application.

Answer (score 0):

What you can patch depends up how you partitioned it in the first place. Did you design it to be patched? If not the best case may be bite the bullet and reinstall a newer version.